# how do i start to use SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

i have sql server 2008. i would like to learn the reporting services. where can i start? can you show me a tutorial that helps me make a simple report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246%28SQL.90%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337423.aspx

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-1/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aafHygddNqc

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/MSReportingServices.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See:

- [SQL Server TechCenter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 – Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511478.aspx)
- [Report Builder 2.0 video tutorial: Create a Basic Table Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd299411.aspx)